I have a fastapi server running on ec2 and frontend deployed over amplify. I get CORS error for the first couple of times I call the API and then not
I have a fastapi server running on ec2 and react frontend deployed over amplify. The backend API works fine when i call through postman, but gives CORS issue when used on frontend. The error is gone if i make the request 2 or 3 times in a row automatically.
I did some research and found it has to do with caching the CORS configuration. My CORS config is shown in code. how do I fix this to make it work from the 1st API call.
In the picture I have made 3 calls, and on 3rd call it works fine.
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from src.views.index import router as root_router

    
app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=os.getenv("trusted_origins").split(","),
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)


app.include_router(root_router)

@app.get("/api/v0")
def read_root():
    return {"success": {"message": "healthy", "code": 200}}


trusted_origins=http://localhost:3002,https://api.dwellner.ca



Look at what the actual response is to the request that triggers the CORS error. CORS headers are not added for requests that generate an exception.

Yes True, So how do I fix that ? Is that a change on my server code ? or some amplify settings ?

I'd start by finding out why the requests fail - if it's always the first requests after a new deployment, there might be some state that hasn't been set up yet, or caches that needs warming where data isn't present yet, but you assumed it would be - or something times out the first time because of missing caches; or it can be any other thing. Start by checking the logs, and verifying what the actual response code is.
